# OPA REGO deconstructing nested array

Tags: opa, rego

I got data something like this:

```
{
  "TENANT1":{ <-- Multiple tenants
    "SITE1":{ <-- Every tenant can have multiple sites
      "SITE1_DEVICE1":[ <-- Every site can have multiple devices
        "TEMP", <-- Just types
        "SET",
        "HUM"
      ],
      "SITE1_DEVICE2":[
        "TEMP"
      ]
    },
    "SITE2":{
      "SITE2_DEVICE1":[
        "TEMP",
        "HUM"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to list every device with types that given tenant is authorized for. This is what I tried:

```
test[devices] {
    devices = data["TENANT1"][_]
}
```

with result:

```
{
  "test":[
    {
      "SITE1_DEVICE1":["TEMP","SET","HUM" ],
      "SITE1_DEVICE2":["TEMP"]
    },
    {
      "SITE2_DEVICE1":["TEMP","HUM"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it somehow possible to have them all on the same level, not divided but it's sites, something like this:

```
{
  "test":[
      "SITE1_DEVICE1":["TEMP","SET","HUM" ],
      "SITE1_DEVICE2":["TEMP"],
      "SITE2_DEVICE1":["TEMP","HUM"]
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below rule:

Rule:

```
test[devices] := ret {
    some key, value in input.TENANT1[_]
    devices := key
    ret := value
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "test": {
        "SITE1_DEVICE1": [
            "TEMP",
            "SET",
            "HUM"
        ],
        "SITE1_DEVICE2": [
            "TEMP"
        ],
        "SITE2_DEVICE1": [
            "TEMP",
            "HUM"
        ]
    }
}
```